# Get values from radgrid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a usercontrol and there is a radgrid included in it. I need to fetch label GetName's text from the radgrid using jquery.I have to check the label's value for each record. Can someone please help me to do it.Thanks.This is my radgrid.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="Gridview1">
  <Columns>
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="tempcolumn">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Header" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Getname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
    </Columns>
   </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show there is in your .aspx page, not the generated one.

In HTML result, the aps:label would be something like that :

```
<span Id="ctl00$blablabla$Getname_random"></span>
```

So, I would suggest to add a class to your label to use it as selector :

```
<asp:Label ID="Getname" runat="server" CssClass="getNameClass"></asp:Label>
```

And then :

```
   $(function () {
            //Move in any trigger function (e.g: click)
            $('.getNameClass').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).text() );
            });
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to loop through the gridview and check the value of the label. Something like. $(gridviewid.clientid).each(function(){ var x="label's value"; }) I am not able to get 'x'.

Comment: $('.getNameClass') returns all the labels Getname of your radgrid. Then, each loop on.